# Is array all NULLs in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, null

Is there an expression that returns TRUE if all the elements of a PostgreSQL array are NULL?

If it was a value other than NULL, I could of course use something like:

```
SELECT 4 = ALL (ARRAY[4,5]::integer[]);
```

However I want to do the ALL operation with an `IS NULL` test, rather than a `= 4` test.  I don't think there's an ALL syntax for this, and the semantics around NULL are compounded with arrays I've not myself been able to think of a form that achieves it. Hence my asking Stack Overflow. ;-)

I know I could write a function in pl/sql or pl/pgsql that does this, but I'd like to see if there's a direct expression before resorting to that.

Comment: Perhaps `generate_series()` can help.

Comment: Yes I suspect I could, though a 'closed form' expression (i.e. no subqueries!) would be preferable.  I'm holding out to see if anyone can think of one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I got the shortest answer, while still preserving `4 = ALL (ARRAY[4,5]::integer[]);` construct:

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6DuB1N4FdcvZdxKiHczu5y/1

```
select
y, true = ALL (select unnest(z) is null)
from x
```

Comment: I like this answer than the other one, so I blogged about it ;-) http://www.anicehumble.com/2011/07/postgresql-unnest-function-do-many.html

Comment: I think that's still technically a subquery but it's short enough.  Thanks.

Comment: I could imagine Postgresql core devs could employ some specialized algorithm if the row source of ALL/ANY/SOME query come from unnested array, i.e. it won't get the same execution plan of typical subquery. Array_fill(my other answer) approach could be faster though, as it doesn't share the execution plan of subquery, looks everything is an in-memory operation; the best way to know is to profile the speed or check the execution plan of different approaches.

Answer (score 18):

```
1 = ALL(arr) IS NULL AND 2 = ALL(arr) IS NULL
```

`1` and `2` can be *any* two distinct numbers.

#### Alternatives and performance

There are many ways. I assembled a quick test case:

```sql
SELECT arr::text
     , -1 = ALL(arr) IS NULL                              AS xsimple
     , 1 = ALL(arr) IS NULL AND 2 = ALL(arr) IS NULL      AS simple
     , array_remove(arr, NULL) = '{}'                     AS array_rem
     , cardinality(array_positions(arr, NULL))
     = cardinality(arr)                                   AS array_pos
     , TRUE = ALL (SELECT unnest(arr) IS NULL)            AS michael
     , (SELECT bool_and(e IS NULL) FROM unnest(arr) e)    AS bool_and
     , NOT EXISTS (SELECT unnest(arr) EXCEPT SELECT null) AS exist
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('{1,2,NULL,3}'::int[])
   , ('{1,1,1}')
   , ('{2,2,2}')
   , ('{NULL,NULL,NULL}')
   , ('{}'::int[])
   ) t(arr);

       arr        | xsimple | simple | array_rem | array_pos | michael | bool_and | exist 
------------------+---------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+-------
 {1,2,NULL,3}     | f       | f      | f         | f         | f       | f        | f
 {1,1,1}          | f       | f      | f         | f         | f       | f        | f
 {2,2,2}          | f       | f      | f         | f         | f       | f        | f
 {NULL,NULL,NULL} | t       | t      | t         | t         | t       | t        | t
 {}               | f       | f      | t         | t         | t       |          | t
```

[`array_remove()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) requires Postgres 9.3 or later.
[`array_positions()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) requires Postgres 9.5 or later.

`chk_michael` is from the [currently accepted answer by @michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854242/939860).
The columns are in order of performance of the expression. Fastest first.
My simple checks dominate performance, with `array_remove()` next. The rest cannot keep up.

The **special case empty array (`{}`)** requires attention. Define the expected result and either pick a fitting expression or add an additional check.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=31297923fdbcf4d757d8c953a163767f)* - with **performance test**
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6f289/2)</sub>

#### How does it work?

The expression `1 = ALL(arr)` yields:

`TRUE`  .. if all elements are `1`
`FALSE` .. if any element is `<> 1` (any element that `IS NOT NULL`)
`NULL`  .. if at least one element `IS NULL` and no element is `<> 1`

So, if we know a single element that ***cannot*** show up (enforced by a `CHECK` constraint), like `-1`, we can simplify to:

```
-1 = ALL(arr) IS NULL
```

If *any* number can show up, check for two distinct numbers. The result can only be `NULL` for both if the array contains nothing but `NULL`. Voilá.

Comment: Your solution differs from the others by returning false on empty arrays. The solution from @ezequiel-tolnay `array_remove(arr, NULL) = '{}'` is almost as fast but returns true for an empty array.

Comment: Good point. I added an empty array to the test case above. What *should* be returned for an empty array when asking the question `Is array all NULLs?` I'd say `false` -  or maybe `null`? But I guess that's up for debate.

Comment: Definitely debatable. If the question instead is `Is array nothing but NULLs?` I would prefer `true` and also `1 = ALL('{}')` and even `NULL = ALL('{}')` yields `true`

Comment: `(1 = ALL(arr) AND 2 = ALL(arr)) IS NOT FALSE` could also be an alternative to get `true` for an empty array

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly proud of this but:

```
=> select not exists (
    select 1
    from (select all unnest(ARRAY[NULL, NULL, NULL]) is null as x) as dt
    where x = 'f'
);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

=> select not exists (
    select 1
    from (select all unnest(ARRAY[NULL, 11, NULL]) is null as x) as dt
    where x = 'f'
);
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Yes, there are subqueries galore but maybe you can make it work or simplify it into something that will work.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to make the code shorter, use EVERY aggregate function

```
create table x
(
y serial,
z int[]
);

insert into x(z) values(array[null,null,null]::int[])
insert into x(z) values(array[null,7,null]::int[])
insert into x(z) values(array[null,3,4]::int[])
insert into x(z) values(array[null,null,null,null]::int[])


with a as
(
    select y, unnest(z) as b
    from x
)
select y, every(b is null)
from a 
group by y
order by y
```

Output:

```
 y | every
---+-------
 1 | t
 2 | f
 3 | f
 4 | t
(4 rows)
```

Another approach, generating NULLs to be used for comparison:

```
select  y, 
    z = 
    (select array_agg(null::int) 
     from generate_series(1, array_upper(z, 1) )) as IsAllNulls
from    x
```

Underlying logic of the code above, this returns true:

```
SELECT ARRAY[NULL,NULL]::int[] = ARRAY[NULL,NULL]::int[]
```

Another approach, use [array_fill](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-array.html)

```
select  y, z = array_fill(null::int, array[ array_upper(z, 1) ] )
from    x
```

Caveat, array construct and array_fill are not symmetrical though, test these:

```
select array[5]

-- array[5] here has different meaning from array[5] above
select array_fill(null::int, array[5])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of variety of options, what I've used before for this is:

```
select array_remove(ARRAY[null::int, null, null], null) = '{}'
```

This method will also return true for no values at all in the array, which is useful when preferring to store a null value instead an empty or all nulls array, eg in an on update trigger:

```
NEW.arrvalue := CASE WHEN array_remove(NEW.arrvalue, null) <> '{}' THEN NEW.arrvalue END;
```

Comment: This is good because it is almost as fast as Erwins but works for both values and null. And it returns the same as `1 = ALL(arr)` for an empty array.