# Check if NULL exists in Postgres array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, null, postgresql-9.1

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11231544/327026), how can I find if a NULL value exists in an array?

Here are some attempts.

```
SELECT num, ar, expected,
  ar @> ARRAY[NULL]::int[] AS test1,
  NULL = ANY (ar) AS test2,
  array_to_string(ar, ', ') <> array_to_string(ar, ', ', '(null)') AS test3
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS num, '{1,2,NULL}'::int[] AS ar, true AS expected
  UNION SELECT 2, '{1,2,3}'::int[], false
) td ORDER BY num;

 num |     ar     | expected | test1 | test2 | test3
-----+------------+----------+-------+-------+-------
   1 | {1,2,NULL} | t        | f     |       | t
   2 | {1,2,3}    | f        | f     |       | f
(2 rows)
```

Only a trick with [`array_to_string`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) shows the expected value. Is there a better way to test this?

Comment: Very similar, except for the Postgres 9.1 angle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695015/how-to-determine-if-null-is-contained-in-an-array-in-postgres

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Postgres 9.5 or later

Use [**`array_position()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). Basically:

```
SELECT array_position(arr, NULL) IS NOT NULL AS array_has_null
```

See demo below.

#### Postgres 9.3 or later

You can test with the built-in functions [`array_remove()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) or [`array_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

#### Postgres 9.1 or any version

If you ***know*** a single element that can never exist in your arrays, you can use this *fast* expression. Say, you have an array of positive numbers, and `-1` can never be in it:

```
-1 = ANY(arr) IS NULL
```

Related answer with detailed explanation:

- [Is array all NULLs in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852312/is-array-all-nulls-in-postgresql/22257626#22257626)

If you *cannot be absolutely sure*, you *could* fall back to one of the expensive but *safe* methods with `unnest()`. Like:

```
(SELECT bool_or(x IS NULL) FROM unnest(arr) x)
```

or:

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM unnest(arr) x WHERE x IS NULL)
```

But you can have *fast and safe* with a `CASE` expression. Use an unlikely number and fall back to the safe method if it should exist. You may want to treat the case `arr IS NULL` separately. See demo below.

#### Demo

```sql
SELECT num, arr, expect
     , -1 = ANY(arr) IS NULL                                    AS t_1   --  50 ms
     , (SELECT bool_or(x IS NULL) FROM unnest(arr) x)           AS t_2   -- 754 ms
     , EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM unnest(arr) x WHERE x IS NULL)     AS t_3   -- 521 ms
     , CASE -1 = ANY(arr)
         WHEN FALSE THEN FALSE
         WHEN TRUE THEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM unnest(arr) x WHERE x IS NULL)
         ELSE NULLIF(arr IS NOT NULL, FALSE)  -- catch arr IS NULL       --  55 ms
      -- ELSE TRUE  -- simpler for columns defined NOT NULL              --  51 ms
       END                                                      AS t_91
     , array_replace(arr, NULL, 0) <> arr                       AS t_93a --  99 ms
     , array_remove(arr, NULL) <> arr                           AS t_93b --  96 ms
     , cardinality(array_remove(arr, NULL)) <> cardinality(arr) AS t_94  --  81 ms
     , COALESCE(array_position(arr, NULL::int), 0) > 0          AS t_95a --  49 ms
     , array_position(arr, NULL) IS NOT NULL                    AS t_95b --  45 ms
     , CASE WHEN arr IS NOT NULL
            THEN array_position(arr, NULL) IS NOT NULL END      AS t_95c --  48 ms
FROM  (
   VALUES (1, '{1,2,NULL}'::int[], true)     -- extended test case
        , (2, '{-1,NULL,2}'      , true)
        , (3, '{NULL}'           , true)
        , (4, '{1,2,3}'          , false)
        , (5, '{-1,2,3}'         , false)
        , (6, NULL               , null)
   ) t(num, arr, expect);
```

Result:

```
 num |  arr        | expect | t_1    | t_2  | t_3 | t_91 | t_93a | t_93b | t_94 | t_95a | t_95b | t_95c
-----+-------------+--------+--------+------+-----+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------
   1 | {1,2,NULL}  | t      | t      | t    | t   | t    | t     | t     | t    | t     | t     | t
   2 | {-1,NULL,2} | t      | f --!! | t    | t   | t    | t     | t     | t    | t     | t     | t
   3 | {NULL}      | t      | t      | t    | t   | t    | t     | t     | t    | t     | t     | t
   4 | {1,2,3}     | f      | f      | f    | f   | f    | f     | f     | f    | f     | f     | f
   5 | {-1,2,3}    | f      | f      | f    | f   | f    | f     | f     | f    | f     | f     | f
   6 | NULL        | NULL   | t --!! | NULL | f   | NULL | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | f     | f     | NULL
```

Note that `array_remove()` and `array_position()` are not allowed for **multi-dimensional arrays**. All expressions to the right of `t_93a` only work for 1-dimenstioal arrays.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8b0375321dd98b6f0b14e42998f4f72b)* - Postgres 13, with more tests
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/324f8/3)</sub>

#### Benchmark setup

The added times are from a **benchmark test with 200k rows in Postgres 9.5**. This is my setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t AS
SELECT row_number() OVER() AS num
     , array_agg(elem) AS arr
     , bool_or(elem IS NULL) AS expected
FROM  (
   SELECT CASE WHEN random() > .95 THEN NULL ELSE g END AS elem  -- 5% NULL VALUES
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE random() > .8)
                   OVER (ORDER BY g) AS grp  -- avg 5 element per array
   FROM   generate_series (1, 1000000) g  -- increase for big test case
   ) sub
GROUP  BY grp;
```

#### Function wrapper

For **repeated use**, I would create a function in Postgres **9.5** like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_has_null (anyarray)
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
 'SELECT array_position($1, NULL) IS NOT NULL';
```

`PARALLEL SAFE` only for Postgres 9.6 or later.

Using a [polymorphic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) input type this works for *any* array type, not just `int[]`.

Make it `IMMUTABLE` to allow performance optimization and index expressions.

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

But don't make it `STRICT`, which would disable "function inlining" and impair performance because `array_position()` is not `STRICT` itself. See:

- [Function executes faster without STRICT modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455177/function-executes-faster-without-strict-modifier)

If you need to catch the case `arr IS NULL`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_has_null (anyarray)
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
 'SELECT CASE WHEN $1 IS NOT NULL
              THEN array_position($1, NULL) IS NOT NULL END';
```

For Postgres **9.1** use the `t_91` expression from above. The rest applies unchanged.

Closely related:

- [How to determine if NULL is contained in an array in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695015/how-to-determine-if-null-is-contained-in-an-array-in-postgres)

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL's [UNNEST(](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)) function is a better choice.You can write a simple function like below to check for NULL values in an array.

```
create or replace function NULL_EXISTS(val anyelement) returns boolean as
$$
select exists (
    select 1 from unnest(val) arr(el) where el is null
);
$$
language sql
```

For example,

```
SELECT NULL_EXISTS(array [1,2,NULL])
      ,NULL_EXISTS(array [1,2,3]);
```

Result:

```
null_exists null_exists 
----------- -------------- 
t           f
```

So, You can use `NULL_EXISTS()` function in your query like below.

```
SELECT num, ar, expected,NULL_EXISTS(ar)
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS num, '{1,2,NULL}'::int[] AS ar, true AS expected
  UNION SELECT 2, '{1,2,3}'::int[], false
) td ORDER BY num;
```

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL 9.5 (I know you spcified 9.1, but anyway) has the `array_position()` function to do just what you want without having to use the horribly inefficient `unnest()` for something as trivial as this (see `test4`):

```
patrick@puny:~$ psql -d test
psql (9.5.0)
Type "help" for help.

test=# SELECT num, ar, expected,
  ar @> ARRAY[NULL]::int[] AS test1,
  NULL = ANY (ar) AS test2,
  array_to_string(ar, ', ') <> array_to_string(ar, ', ', '(null)') AS test3,
  coalesce(array_position(ar, NULL::int), 0) > 0 AS test4
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS num, '{1,2,NULL}'::int[] AS ar, true AS expected
  UNION SELECT 2, '{1,2,3}'::int[], false
) td ORDER BY num;
 num |     ar     | expected | test1 | test2 | test3 | test4
-----+------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------
   1 | {1,2,NULL} | t        | f     |       | t     | t
   2 | {1,2,3}    | f        | f     |       | f     | f
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this

```
select 
    array_position(array[1,null], null) is not null
```

> [array_position](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-array.html) - returns the subscript of the first occurrence of the second argument in the array, starting at the element indicated by the third argument or at the first element (array must be one-dimensional)

Comment: A little more explanation would have been very helpful.

Comment: This does not seem to add anything new.