# NULLS in ARRAY_AGG and Checking for Nulls in Array (Postgres 9.5.1)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using `ARRAY_AGG` on a field with potentially NULL values and I then want to check the array later for any NULL entires. For example:

```
WITH test AS
(
SELECT 'A' AS call_id, NULL AS outcome
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS call_id, 'success' AS outcome
)

SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT call_id, ARRAY_AGG(outcome) AS outcome
          FROM test
          GROUP BY call_id
       ) AS sub
  WHERE outcome && ARRAY[NULL]
```

But the result of this query is no rows are returned. The `ARRAY_AGG` will create one row with `call_id` = 'A' and the `outcome` array equal to {,'success'}. How do I check this array for NULL values?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848009/check-if-null-exists-in-postgres-array/34848472#34848472

Comment: It is funny, but `... where array_position(outcome, null) is not null` should work.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848009/check-if-null-exists-in-postgres-array

-1 = ANY(_product_id) IS NULL

Might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Apart from writing a function, there is no way I can think of that will do this directly with the array. But what about counting the `NULL` values during aggregation?

```
WITH test (call_id, outcome) AS
(
  values 
    ('A', null), 
    ('A', 'success'), 
    ('B', 'failure')
)
SELECT *
FROM ( 
  SELECT call_id, 
         array_agg(outcome) AS outcome, 
         count(case when outcome is null then 1 end) as null_count
  FROM test
  GROUP BY call_id
) AS sub
where null_count > 0;
```

You can also integrate that directly into the select statement using a having clause:

```
SELECT call_id, 
       array_agg(outcome) AS outcome
FROM test
GROUP BY call_id
having count(case when outcome is null then 1 end) > 0
```

Another option would be to replace the `NULL` values with something that can't be in the `outcome` column and then check for that "magic" value.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* try un-nesting your `outcome` array and checking it for the existence of null values. Like so:

```
WITH test AS
(
  SELECT 'A' AS call_id, null AS outcome
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS call_id, 'success' AS outcome
)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT call_id, ARRAY_AGG(outcome) AS outcome
  FROM test
  GROUP BY call_id
) AS sub
WHERE EXISTS (select * from unnest(outcome) where unnest is null)
```