# Query postgres integer array with Rails where values are not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to build a scope for my Contradiction model where the `evaluation_parameters` attribute only contains non NULL values.
I have records where this attribute is completely empty `{}` or where one of the two values is nil `{123, NULL}` and I would like to not have these in my result.

Here is my migration:

```
add_column :contradictions, :evaluation_parameters, :integer, array: true, default: []
```

I already tried the following query which returns only records with an empty array

```
Contradiction.all.where.not("NULL = ANY (evaluation_parameters)")
```

Any suggestions  on how I could do this ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here [Check if NULL exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848009/check-if-null-exists-in-postgres-array/34848472#34848472)
My final query looks like this :

```
Contradiction.where.not(evaluation_parameters: '{}').where.not("-1 = ANY(evaluation_parameters) IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

`evaluation_parameters` should probably be `:text`, not `:integer`.

The query you're looking for then is:

`Contradiction.where("evaluation_parameters = '{}'")`

This would fetch all contradictions which have evaluation_parameters equal to empty array.

Comment: Thank you for your input, however doing this only gives me the results with an empty array. What I want is all contradictions where both values in the array are NOT null (e.g. `{123, 123}`). I also don't see why I would have to convert to `:text` since I'm storing ids in this array.