# Add array element if it's not contained already

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to add integer to an array if does not exist in the array, yet. But the following creates duplicate values:

```
User.update(
{
    'topics': sequelize.fn('array_append', sequelize.col('topics'), topicId),
},
{where: {uuid: id}})
```

Is there an equivalent function in PostgreSQL/sequelize to MongoDB $addToSet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet):

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case `$addToSet` does nothing to that array.

This SQL command does what you ask:

```sql
UPDATE "user"
SET    topics = topics || topicId
WHERE  uuid = id
AND    NOT (topics @> ARRAY[topicId]);
```

`@>` being the array contains operator and `||` array-to-element concatenation in this case. [Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

Related:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)

Does not work for `null` values. In this case consider: `array_position(topics, topicId) IS NULL`. See:

- [Check if NULL exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848009/check-if-null-exists-in-postgres-array/34848472#34848472)

You *could* wrap this into a simple function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_append_uniq (anyarray, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyarray
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
 'SELECT CASE WHEN array_position($1,$2) IS NULL THEN $1 || $2 ELSE $1 END;'
```

And use it like:

```
...
SET    topics = f_array_append_uniq (topics, topicId)
...
```

But the query at the top only even writes a new row version if the column value actually changes. To achieve the same (without function):

```sql
UPDATE "user"
SET    topics = topics || topicId
WHERE  uuid = id
AND    array_position(topics,topicId) IS NOT NULL;
```

The last one being my favorite.

See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved.

```
const user = User.findOne({where: {id}})
User.update({topics: (user.topics.indexOf('topicId') > -1) ? user.topics : Sequelize.fn('array_append', Sequelize.col('topics'), topicId) }, {where: {id}})
```

Though it definitely feels like there is a better way.