# ActiveRecord/Postgres - find all entities with nulls in array field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Given a model *User* and a string array column *device_ids*, how can I query for all Users that have nulls as an element of this array column?

E.g., some of the users has invalid values for device_ids:

```
user.device_ids
=> [null, "XYZABCDEFGH"]
```

I tried querying as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848009/check-if-null-exists-in-postgres-array/34848472#34848472)...

```
User.where.not("(-1 = ANY(device_ids)) IS NULL")
```

... but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
```

Is there any other ways to get all the users in a single query?

Comment: As far as SQL goes you can use something like `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM unnest(device_ids) a(e) WHERE e IS NULL)`. (But I have no idea how to write that in for Rails.) But I advise against using arrays, if you cannot handle them atomically, i.e. you need to query single elements of them. Using the relational way is far less stressful.

Comment: thank you so much @stickybit! This helped me a lot. The only reason I'm querying single elements is because I need to remove the invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help @sticky bit! My final solution was:

> User.where("EXISTS (SELECT * FROM unnest(device_ids) a(e) WHERE e IS NULL)")