# Jooq ArrayAgg#isNull not working as expected

Tags: sql, jooq

I have a project which uses jooq + postgres with multiple tables and relations between them.

while I was creating a `select` query with jooq I had to use `arrayAgg` for my specific scenario.

`dslContext.select(arrayAgg(tableName.INTEGER_LETS_SAY).as("static_name")`

the specific column `INTEGER_LETS_SAY` is nullable.
when the results passed in `arrayAgg` are all `null` then the response of the postgres is '{null}' ( tested with `getQuery().getSql()` ) but the `where` statement cannot return `true` for all the methods I tried.

for example :

- `field("static_name", Long[].class).isNull()`
- `field("static_name", Long[].class).equal(new Long[] {null})`
- `field("static_name", Long[].class).equal(DSL.castNull(Long[].class)`
- `field("static_name", Long[].class).cast(String.class).eq(DSL.value("{null}")))`
- `field("static_name", Long[].class).cast(String.class).eq(DSL.value("'{null}'")))`

any clue what am I doing wrong?

Note : I did try the query with plain sql and `static_name = '{null}'` worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{NULL}` is PostgreSQL's text representation of an array containing one SQL `NULL` value. You can try it like this:

```sql
select (array[null]::int[])::text ilike '{null}' as a
```

It yields:

```
a   |
----|
true|
```

Note, I'm using `ilike` for case insensitive comparison. On my installation, I'm getting `{NULL}`, not `{null}`. If you wanted to compare things as text, you could do it using [`Field.likeIgnoreCase()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#likeIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)). E.g. this works for me:

```java
System.out.println(ctx.select(
    field(val(new Long[] { null }).cast(String.class).likeIgnoreCase("{null}")).as("a")
).fetch());
```

Producing:

```
+----+
|a   |
+----+
|true|
+----+
```

But much better, do not work with the text representation. Instead, [follow this suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854242/521799). In SQL:

```sql
select true = all(select a is null from unnest(array[null]::int[]) t (a)) as a
```

In jOOQ:

```java
System.out.println(ctx.select(
    field(inline(true).eq(all(
        select(field(field(name("a")).isNull()))
        .from(unnest(val(new Long[] { null })).as("t", "a"))
    ))).as("a")
).fetch());
```

It gets a bit verbose because of all the wrapping `Condition` in `Field<Boolean>` using [`DSL.field(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(org.jooq.Condition)).

Alternatively, use e.g. `NUM_NONNULLS()` (Credits to [Vik Fearing](https://mobile.twitter.com/pg_xocolatl/status/1322101077983055873) for this appraoch):

```java
System.out.println(ctx.select(
    field("num_nonnulls(variadic {0})", INTEGER, val(new Long { null }))
).fetch());
```

Comment: lemme check that one. I found a workaround with array functions on sql but cannot be recreated in jooq as a function is missing. 
`cardinality(array_remove(the_array,NULL)) = 0 ` ( the function missing is cardinality )

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis: You can always use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) for missing functions. There's no such thing as "cannot be used in jOOQ"

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis: I've updated my answer with an example using `NUM_NONNULLS()`. Credits to [Vik Fearing](https://mobile.twitter.com/pg_xocolatl/status/1322101077983055873)

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis: You're using arrays. They almost only exist on PostgreSQL